# Problem with Serial library

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a problem when i use serial.h library, this is my test code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "serial/serial.h"
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "Serial");

std::string port = "/dev/ttyUSB1";
unsigned long baud = 9600;
serial::Serial myserial(port, baud, serial::Timeout(250));
if(!myserial.isOpen())
myserial.open();
size_t size = 4;
std::string read;
while (ros::ok())
{
read = myserial.read(size);
for(int x=0; x<size; x++)

{
ROS_INFO("Valores leidos: %s ", read.c_str());
ROS_INFO(" ");
}
ROS_INFO("\n");
ros::spinOnce();
}
return 0;
};
```

and when i compile, this is the error:

```
CMakeFiles/Prueba_serial.dir/src/prueba_serial.cpp.o: In the function 'main':
prueba_serial.cpp:(.text.startup+0x145): reference toserial::Serial::Serial(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >const&, unsigned int, serial::Timeout, serial::bytesize_t, serial::parity_t, serial::stopbits_t,serial::flowcontrol_t)' sin definirprueba_serial.cpp:(.text.startup+0x155): reference to serial::Serial::isOpen() const' not define
prueba_serial.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1c1): reference toserial::Serial::read[abi:cxx11](unsigned long)'not defineprueba_serial.cpp:(.text.startup+0x606): reference to serial::Serial::~Serial()' not define
prueba_serial.cpp:(.text.startup+0x64c): reference toserial::Serial::open()' not defineprueba_serial.cpp:(.text.startup+0x660): reference to serial::Serial::~Serial()' not define

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

thanks and sorry for my English

pd: sorry for the duplicate question.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279249/problem-with-serial-library/) by [Skained](https://answers.ros.org/users/33217/skained/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-01-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This tells us that most likely you forgot to add the `serial` package to your `find_package(catkin COMPONENT ..)` line in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

See also the Catkin documentation on [adding catkin library dependencies](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/catkin_library_dependencies.html).

Without seeing your `CMakeLists.txt` this is a guess though.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-01-09**:
beat me to it :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-09**:
Had to deal with the duplicate, so thought might as well answer it :)

**Comment by [Skained](https://answers.ros.org/users/33217/skained/) on 2018-01-09**:
ok.. yes, this is the problem, my fail

thank you very much